# Access NUnit Test Name within TestCaseSource

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a series of tests where I want to use the same testcase data for a bunch of different tests.

eg:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("TestData")] 
public void Test1(Foo foo)
{
    // test 1
}

[Test, TestCaseSource("TestData")] 
public void Test2(Foo foo)
{
    // test 2
}

private static IEnumerable TestData() 
{
   TestCaseData data; 

   data = new TestCaseData(new Foo("aaa"));
   yield return data; 

   data = new TestCaseData(new Foo("bbb"));
   yield return data; 
}
```

This leads to a series of tests that report like so:

```
Namespace.That.Is.Very.Long.TestClass.Test1(Namespace.That.Is.Very.Long.Foo)  
Namespace.That.Is.Very.Long.TestClass.Test1(Namespace.That.Is.Very.Long.Foo)  
Namespace.That.Is.Very.Long.TestClass.Test2(Namespace.That.Is.Very.Long.Foo)  
Namespace.That.Is.Very.Long.TestClass.Test2(Namespace.That.Is.Very.Long.Foo)
```

...which isn't hugely meaningful when you don't know what 'foo' failed..

If [as suggested in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332726/nunit-set-test-name-programmatically) I set the name like this:

```
   data = new TestCaseData(new Foo("aaa"));
   data.SetName("foo=aaa");
   yield return data;
```

...then all my tests come out looking like this:

```
foo=aaa   
foo=bbb  
foo=aaa  
foo=bbb
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to get the current test method name. That would appear, [as described in this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588486/how-to-access-the-nunit-test-name-programmatically) be done via TestContext.

However, while TestContext.Current.Test exists, all the properties (like Name) throw a NullReferenceException when trying to access them.

Is there some other way to achieve this goal of providing more useful information in the test name?

Comment: What is your reason for not using the information provided by the failing assert, lack of exception etc.?

Comment: I can use the information provided by the failing assert, but it doesn't tell me what testcase data was provided. Plus, on CI platforms like TeamCity, testcases with the same output name are aggregated and appear as one. "Test {x} was run 7 times, failed 1 times" (or similar)

Comment: @JamesFaix for me, `TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name` works just fine and outputs `foo=aaa` in the case provided in question, so I suppose that was fixed. So you can just use `SetName` + `TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name`.

Comment: This could be a difference in versions. I'm on nunit 3.6.  From every experiment I've tried, test context data is not available when test case lists are being read by the test runner.  The cases are read before the tests start, and so there is not yet any test context.  There will be a `TestContext.CurrentContext` that you can access, but most properties are null, and in this particular case, I get a `NullReferenceException` when trying to reference `TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name` in the test case list property.

Comment: Maybe also depends on a runner. I use Resharpers test runner and latest version of nunit from nuget package (that is 3.7.1 I think). It displays all test names correctly and `Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name)` writes test name to output without any exceptions. PS: just downgraded to 3.6.0 and it still works fine with Resharper runner.

Comment: @JamesFaix `TestName` property has built in string formatting mechanism the solves your problem. just add `.SetName("case 1 {m}");` to the `TestCaseData` instance.

Comment: @Evk I have tried to make it pass in 5 different versions of NUnit + with\out resharper and faced the same problem as JamesFaix. I think that maybe you've found a bug because as I know NUnit's source code it should be null... In the answer I've wrote you can see a link to the class that is respossiable to build the test.

Comment: @OldFox so running exactly the code provided in OP, and adding `Console.WriteLine("output:" + TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);` in Test1 or Test2 throws null reference for you when running with resharper?

Comment: @Evk Not in the test methods, it throws in `TestData`.  `TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name` will work fine in `Test1` or `Test2` but not in `TestData`. You won't be able to change the output name durring the execution of the test methods without changing in NUnit's engine or by writing an extension.

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood the question. Didn't realize OP needs test name in TestData method (just could not imagine why would he).

Answer (score 54):

The property `TestName` has a support in NUnit 3 for string formatting.

Here's an example usage:

```
private static IEnumerable TestData()
{
    TestCaseData data;

    data = new TestCaseData(new Foo("aaa"))
                            .SetName("case 1 {m}");
    yield return data;

    data = new TestCaseData(new Foo("bbb"));
    yield return data;
}
```

Will generate the following out put:

[image]

As you can see the test names the of the first case contains the custom prefix + the method name.

Use [this link](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Generation-of-Test-Names-Spec) for more information about NUnit's string formating capability.

2 classes are resposable for this action [NUnitTestCaseBuilder (line 83)](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Internal/Builders/NUnitTestCaseBuilder.cs#L83) and `TestNameGenerator` method `.GetDisplayName()`.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for including references to the NUnit documentation

Comment: I had NO idea that NUnit had the concept of tokens for formatting names.  Thank you for the links, this is great to know!

Comment: @user2338408 you welcome! Actually I didn't know this capability until last december when I thought that I'll have enough free time for contributing to NUnit, then I looked over NUnit source code and I read the entire documention...

Comment: For proper grouping and running tests from VS context menu, we needed to add formatting in form {m}(case 1). It seems like it has to start with {m}.

Comment: Note `.SetArgDisplay` may be the better (and possibly newer?) alternative here. You don't change the whole test name, but really only the names of the test arguments you generate.

Comment: The link in the original comment is not working, the correct url is  [Template-Based Test Naming](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Template-Based-Test-Naming.html)

Comment: Using `.SetName` is giving me an orphan test for the test method as well as the number of `TestCaseData` I return. And also, they were not grouped like when using `TestCase`. `.SetArgDisplayNames` fixes all that. NUnit version: 3.13.3

Comment: @OldFox Maybe, if you time, a little update including all the comments? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a perfect answer, but the best solution I've found so far is that I create a wrapper for the TestData emitter that gets passed in as the TestCaseSource.

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("TestData_Test1")] 
public void Test1(Foo foo)
{
    // test 1
}

[Test, TestCaseSource("TestData_Test2")] 
public void Test2(Foo foo)
{
    // test 2
}


private static IEnumerable TestData_Test1() 
{
   return TestData_Base("Test1"); 
} 

private static IEnumerable TestData_Test2() 
{
   return TestData_Base("Test2"); 
} 

private static IEnumerable TestData_Base(string testName) 
{
   TestCaseData data; 

   data = new TestCaseData(new Foo("aaa"));
   data.SetName(string.Format("{0}(Foo=aaa)", testName)); 
   yield return data; 

   data = new TestCaseData(new Foo("bbb"));
   data.SetName(string.Format("{0}(Foo=bbb)", testName)); 
   yield return data; 
}
```

This means that my tests are now emitted from NCrunch, TeamCity, etc as

```
Test1(Foo=aaa)
Test1(Foo=bbb)
Test2(Foo=aaa)
Test2(Foo=bbb)
```

Which is at least better than the completely useless default.

Comment: You could start with a static list of `Foo` instances you want to test, then use that in your `TestData_Base` method to generate the `TestCaseData` instances from them. This would reduce the duplication of having to specify "aaa" in both the Foo constructor and the `SetName` method. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37216934/20570.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are lucky to use .NET 4.5, you can use the [CallerMemberName] attribute on the last argument of the constructor of a new TestCaseSourceEx attribute extending TestCaseSource, which will give you the test method name inside the attribute constructor.

Here's a working sample:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class TestCaseSourceEx : TestCaseSourceAttribute
{
    public TestCaseSourceEx(Type sourceType, string sourceName, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = null)
        : base(sourceType, sourceName)
    {

    }
    public TestCaseSourceEx(string sourceName, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = null)
        : base(sourceName)
    {

    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class SampleTests
{
    public IEnumerable List = new[] { new string[] { "test-username", "test-password" } };

    [Test, TestCaseSourceEx("List")]
    public void SampleTests_LoginTest(string username, string password)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps you get `methodName` into the TestCaseData Name property....unless I am missing something obvious?

Comment: CallerMemberName attribute argument brings in the method name. Was introduced in 4.5. Previously the only option was to dig into the call stack. If you observe the code, we don't call that constructor argument, it's being called by the runtime.

Comment: I understand that part, what I don't understand is that now you have `methodName` available in the TestCaseSourceAttribute class, how do I use it to set the name of the test?  As I understand I need to call `TestCaseData.SetName(string name)` to override the default.  But how can I make `methodName` available when I call that?

Comment: Your use case seems little bit different. In this example I use the method name to generate tests data from a custom data source in e.g. json files in a  folder named after particular testmethod names.  https://github.com/evisar/nunit-testcaseattribute-externaldata/blob/master/ExternalTestCaseSourceAttribute.cs

Answer (score 1):

After long googling i've found my solution which was alot easier than those posted above:

1st. In test case I've added another parameter: string testName:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("TestData")] 
public void Test1(string testName, Foo foo)
{
    // test 1
}

[Test, TestCaseSource("TestData")] 
public void Test2(String testName, Foo foo)
{
    // test 2
}
```

2nd. in TestCaseData I've added another parameter which shows unique property of Foo object eg. name

```
private static IEnumerable TestData() 
{
   TestCaseData data; 

   Foo data1 = new Foo("aaa");
   data = new TestCaseData(data1.name, data1);
   yield return data; 

   Foo data2 = new Foo("bbb");
   data = new TestCaseData(data2.name, data2);
   yield return data; 
}
```

In NUnit runner the result are displayed like this:

```
Namespace.That.Is.Very.Long.TestClass.Test1("aaa", Namespace.That.Is.Very.Long.Foo)
Namespace.That.Is.Very.Long.TestClass.Test1("bbb", Namespace.That.Is.Very.Long.Foo)
```

This makes tests separate in output window, while i'm still able to see exactly which test is being runned.

Comment: Thanks - after about two days of tearing my hair out over this problem, I've also ended up doing this. It is an abuse of the test case parameters, and could require lots of changes to test case signatures if many tests use the same data source, but it works for me in absence of anything else that works.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
[TestCase("aaa")] 
[TestCase("bbb")] 
public void MainTest(string str)
{
  Assert.DoesNotThrow(()=> Test1(new Foo(str)));
  Assert.DoesNotThrow(()=> Test2(new Foo(str)));
}

public void Test1(Foo foo)
{
    // test 1
}

public void Test2(Foo foo)
{
    // test 2
}
```

UPD:

```
[TestCase("aaa")] 
[TestCase("bbb")] 
public void Test1(string str)
{
    var foo = new Foo(str);
    // rest of the test
}

[TestCase("aaa")] 
[TestCase("bbb")] 
public void Test2(string str)
{
    var foo = new Foo(str);
    // rest of the test
}
```

Comment: That'll only let me see one test fail at a time.

Comment: Yes, this is not exactly what you are looking for. From my experience with unit tests, the best practices are to have the unit test as explicit as possible. Even if it means duplicate some code in different tests. I know that it sounds counter intuitive, but in tests, I prefer looking at a single test and understand what is going on there. So following this recommendation, you can duplicate the TestCase for each test. I edited the answer.

Comment: We're not using TestCase because the actual thing we want to pass is more complex (in this case, a method delegate, but the principle is for something that can't be passed in an attribute).

Comment: I added an answer which shows the work-around that I've actually ended up using. It's not great, but better than the other alternatives I've found.